# Postgres lateral join refer to output row

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have the following setup:

```
CREATE TABLE A(id INT);
CREATE TABLE B(id INT);
CREATE TABLE C(aid INT, bid INT);
```

I would like to do the following:

```
INSERT INTO C SELECT A.id as aid, (SELECT B.id FROM B WHERE A.id=B.id) 
AS bid FROM A WHERE bid is not NULL;
```

However it gives an error that the column bid doesn't exist. So is there a way to refer to an output row in lateral join or make insert only in case `bid` is not null?

I would like to keep the lateral join though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't reference the alias like that, you need to wrap the select:

```
INSERT INTO C 
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT A.id as aid, 
           (SELECT B.id FROM B WHERE A.id=B.id) AS bid 
    FROM A 
) t
WHERE bid is not NULL;
```